# Flutter/Dart : Sort list by last letter of the word

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list.

```
List<String> myList=['Jacob','Jane','Cedric','Angela','Gerald'];
```

I want to sort this list according to the last letter of the words.

The result I expected:

```
List<String> myList=['Angela','Jacob','Cedric','Gerald','Jane'];
```

How can I do that in Dart?

Comment: assuming you've read the documentation (https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.5/dart-core/List/sort.html), what are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't know why can't I post an answer here but, there you have it:

`List<String> myList = ['Jacob', 'Jane', 'Cedric', 'Angela', 'Gerald'];`
`List<String> reversedList = List.generate(myList.length, (i) => myList[i].split('').reversed.join(''));`
`reversedList.sort();`
`List<String> sortedList = List.generate(reversedList.length, (i) => reversedList[i].split('').reversed.join(''));`
`print(sortedList);`

Comment: Thank you. The site's administrators were not as kind as you, so they closed the post.

Comment: please try this `myList.sort((a, b) => a.split('').reversed.join().compareTo(b.split('').reversed.join()));`